# Styling multiple validation controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, controls

I'm using the validation controls (namely `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator`) and am having a bit of trouble getting them to style correctly.

The problem is that because I have markup like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequiredValidator" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="Email field is required" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailFormatValidator" ControlToValidate="Email" ValidationExpression="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid email address"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

the `RegularExpressionValidator` gets pushed over to the side because the `RegularExpressionValidator` is in the way. Perhaps a graphical representation will help:

[image: The problem]

The "Invalid email address" error label is meant to be right next to the input box, but the other validator pushes it to the side.

How can I make the validators invisible until they fire an error message or make them float on top of one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key is Display='Dynamic', a propery of Validators.

Comment: Ah, yes. I did already try that but it didn't show up any different in the design view of Visual Studio so I assumed that wasn't it. Thank you :)